# Why doesn't the Delegate pattern belong ot 23 Design patterns from GoF?

Tags: design-patterns

It is a design pattern according to wikipedia, yet it is not mentioned as one of the 23 patterns in GoF book. Why?

Comment: This question does not belong to SO. It should have been posted to Programmers SE instead.

Answer (score 6):

The **Gang of Four** treat *delegation* in a general way, it is an important concept (like *inheritance*, etc.) in *object-oriented software design*. 
For me it is also reasonable to think of them as a design concept, which is more general than a specific design pattern. Furthermore delegation will be used in many different design patterns.

---

**Could also be interesting for you:**

I also like the [Head First Design Pattern Book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596007126.do) where you can also find (in my opinion) a good separation between basics, principles and patterns:

**OO Basics**

- Abstraction
- Encapsulation
- Polymorphism
- Inheritance

**OO Principles**

- Encapsulate what varies
- Favor composition over inheritance
- Program to interfaces, not implementations
- etc...

**OO Patterns**

- Observer
- MVC
- etc...